# Tell a sequence in which there comes three consecutive even numbers after three odd numbers indefinitely?

Tags: sequences-and-series

For example, in triangular numbers $1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55\dots$, two evens come after two odds. I want something like it for three odds and three evens.

Comment: Does '1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 8, 10, 12, ...' not satisfy your constraint?  Without knowing more about what you need it's impossible to give a good answer to this question.

Comment: well, 3,5,7,4,6,8,2,2,2,2,2 etc. (all 2s) 
This is just to say: Any sequence is mathematically logically, see comments here:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632321/find-the-next-number-in-this-sequence/632338#632338

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sequence $a_n = \lceil n/3\rceil$ works.

The notation $\lceil m \rceil$ indicates the smallest integer not greater than $m$ (the "ceiling").  So the sequence for $n = 1, 2, 3, ...$ is $a_n = 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, ...$

Or, the more technical name for this sequence is the [positive integers repeated three times](https://oeis.org/A008620).  (Which is actually an incorrect name, as each integer is repeated just twice; it's written, it's repeated, and it's repeated a second time.  But who's counting?)

Comment: I dont understand an and floor here. Please write like this 1,2,3,4,....

Comment: Actually I just changed it to ceiling because $n$ are the natural numbers (usually).

Comment: I edited my answer.